# SQL Query to get users and orders data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables in my app that I need to get data as follow

(will use simple table structures for ease)

Table 1 : Users

```
user_id -> int
user_name -> varchar
user_location -> text
```

Table 2 : Orders

```
order_id -> int
sender_id -> int
receiver_id -> int
order_price -> decimal
created_at -> date
```

What I need is to get the order price and date + both sender and receiver names and locations. I tried below query but its returns nothing :

```
SELECT
    orders.price ,
    (users.adress) AS senderLocation , 
    (users.adress) AS receiverLocation FROM orders
JOIN users ON orders.sender_id = users.id and orders.receiver_id = users.id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to select two different users for one orders then you should join `orders` table with `user` table twice. For example:

```
SELECT 
  orders.price , 
  (senders.adress) AS senderLocation , 
  (receivers.adress) AS receiverLocation FROM orders
JOIN users as senders ON orders.sender_id = senders.id 
JOIN users as receivers ON orders.receiver_id = receivers.id
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried your solution but i missed the JOIN alias so it didn't works

Answer (score 1):

You `JOIN` clause cannot be fullfilled, unless you have `sender_id = receiver_id` in your `orders_table`, which is very unlikely.

You want two `JOIN`s, one for the sender and the other for the receiver :

```
SELECT 
    orders.price , 
    (users1.adress) AS senderLocation , 
    (users2.adress) AS receiverLocation 
FROM orders
INNER JOIN users AS users1 ON orders.sender_id   = users1.id 
INNER JOIN users AS users2 ON orders.receiver_id = users2.id
```